# WebElement in selenium select with attr

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, css-selectors

I like to select this tag in the page using `selenium` in `java`

```
<input class="btn btn-success addReportBtn" type="submit" />
```

here is what I've tried so far:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[type=submit]"));
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("//input[@type='submit']"));
```

I get these exception for both of them respectively:

> org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"input[type=submit]"}
>
> org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified

if I use `Jsoup` I can easily get it by doing:

```
System.out.println(document.select("input[type=submit]"));
```

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As pointed out by @Jason, you are seriously mixing up XPath expression and CSS selector syntaxes. Correct expressions would be:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='submit']"));
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[type=submit]"));
```

Note that I would not only check the button type since usually there are multiple submit buttons on a page. There is that `addReportBtn` class I would rely the locator on:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input.addReportBtn"));
```

And that also gives a plus one to readability.

Comment: I was just going to edit my answer and mention about selecting the element by class instead of type. Upvoted. :)

Comment: I feel like a dope now, select by class was the best

Comment: @nafas - alecxe gave a better answer. Do accept his instead of mine.

Comment: I'd definitely agree with the `input.addReportBtn`.  that class seems very specific.

Answer (score 3):

Try these:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='submit']"));
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[type='submit']"));
```